# How to preserve line breaks in C# code documentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-documentation

For many years, one could use the `<code/>` element for all kinds of fixed format text as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/code).  The documentation specifically mentions "multiple lines of code" and examples (like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/example)) are showing how this used to work for multi-line code examples.

However, recent versions of Visual Studio (2017, 2019) started to format the content of `<code/>` as freely flowing text, ignoring any line breaks.  (If the element is in a class summary, the effect can be seen when hovering over the class name.)

So, suppose I have to put an XML snippet into the codedoc.  I need newlines to be preserved, ideally without having to mark them with `<br/>`, so that they can be easily copy and pasted in and out.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in [`<example>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/example) tag:

> The example tag lets you specify an example of how to use a method or other library member. This commonly involves using the code tag.

And example from docs:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The GetZero method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// This sample shows how to call the <see cref="GetZero"/> method.
    /// <code>
    /// class TestClass
    /// {
    ///     static int Main()
    ///     {
    ///         return GetZero();
    ///     }
    /// }
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    public static int GetZero()
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Same behavior.    I tested using `code` inside an `example` inside a `summary` and it ended up as if the `example` just wasn't there.  Of course, if I instead hid the example so well that VS would never find it and try to format it inside the IDE, then I would not be bothered by how it gets formatted.  But that's not my goal.

Answer (score 0):

I always use 
    `\n`
to create a new line.

Comment: And it gets displayed as `\n` whenever the context is XML codedoc.